Rejection of samples suspected of not coming of the target population
Say, there is a stationary process that should resemble a Gaussian distribution with 'known' mean and variance.  Iid samples in triplicates (or n-plicates) are taken from it.  It is also known that some samples can become contaminated i.e. include observation(s) from some other distribution (of different shape, mean, and/or variance).
It is assumed that this contamination could manifest itself by producing samples with improbably high ranges.  Blood pressure measurements could serve as an example.  In this case, 'odd' measurements, not representative of the variable being measured, slip in occasionally and while their origin is debatable, they can easily be the result of both the occasional temporal fluctuation of the blood pressure itself during the measurement (thus artificially increasing the triplicate's range) as well as the quirks of the instrument and the method.  This is considered contamination as such outliers are mechanically introduced by the measurement technique/setup and are clinically irrelevant.
Consequently, each n-plicate sample's range is evaluated and compared to a cut-off value chosen based on the assumed 'clean' Gaussian parent distribution.  If the value is exceeded, the sample is rejected and not included in the analysis.
My question is this (with triplicates as an example, and assuming that the procedure is acceptable: which of the following two approaches would be more statistically meaningful?

if the first two of the individual observations exceed the allowed maximum range, reject them and start the next triplicate sample from the next observation.

take the third sample anyway to conclude the triplicate sampling procedure, then reject it.


The first option guarantees (given the above procedure) that the sample will be rejected regardless of the third observation that hasn't been taken yet but the rejection criterion is based on the range of triplicate and not the difference between two adjacent measurements.
Here is the context that hopefully justifies asking this question.  Again, using blood pressure (BP) measurements as an example.  There are several standards and recommendations on how BP measurements should be done.  The reasons for disagreements are that a) the BP itself varies on several time scales, constantly, b) the uncertainty of most measurement methods is on par with the BP short-term variability itself, c) as it stands, in clinical practice spot measurements are the current standard, d) one has to make a clinical decision based on them and either treat or not treat the patient - and that's highly consequential.
While still imperfect, the proliferation of automated oscillometric BP monitors allows for taking several spot measurements at a time.  They will be scattered no matter what you do (try it if you don't believe me), but if done carefully, the short-term scatter is meaningful - it is expected, but if it exceeds certain values it's reasonable to assume that the measurement is likely contaminated (as defined above) and thus not helpful for the diagnosis.  But the censoring process should not be done, as it often is, arbitrarily by e.g. always throwing out the first or the highest value as it biases the measurements and consequently the diagnosis.
Taking the median of the triplicate (as opposed to the mean) already has the property of filtering singular high (or low) values.  Practice shows that some triplicates even if median-filtered should be rejected as they are not meaningful or representative of the variable being measured.
So, this brings me back to the original question: assuming that the valid triplicate measurement can be modelled as an iid sample from a Gaussian distribution with 'known' variance and that the occasional invalid/contaminated one can be detected and rejected by setting the limit on the range of a such a triplicate, what are the consequences of taking the shortcut (1) as opposed to not taking the shortcut (2) and sampling the triplicate to completion before rejecting it?

I'm having trouble with this post for two reasons.  First, the data-rejection approach described here is in general questionable, so if it is valid, there must be some stronger assumptions or justification than stated here and they might be important considerations.  Second, you haven't asked any clear question: "comment on it" is not the kind of question we can address here.  Could you be more specific?

@whuber, Thanks.  I edited the question trying to make it more specific and applicable.

That helps.  But could you give us a sense of purpose?  After all, the meaning of "more appropriate" depends on what you are trying to accomplish with these data and the answer conceivably depends on that.

"take the third sample anyway to conclude the triplicate sampling procedure, then reject it." I don't follow this sentence. You want to take a third sample, even when you are sure to reject it? Why? What is the point of concluding the procedure?

If a sample is known to be corrupted, there is no point analysing it. If based on a single value, we can tell that the entry will be corrupted we might as well discard it. For example, say I look at BMI and I see a height of 478cm, there are no 300+ cm people so there is no point in collecting weight measurements for that subject.

@usεr11852 yes, but that is obvious. What is the point of the question, or is it just that obvious point? Maybe the question contemplates difficulties like measurements of a height of 220cm, which is borderline? Or there are reasons to complete the entire sequence of measurements (even when we know it will be discarded) before starting over?

The doctor of my kids just takes measurements untill it is the desired value. And the underlying idea is that a kid with too high blood pressure won't be able to pass that test.

@SextusEmpiricus One concern may be that the distribution of the range of a triplicate sample (on which the reject criterion is based) is not the same as the distribution of the absolute value of the difference between a pair of adjacent observations that causes them to be rejected, making the inclusion of the next observation in the next triplicate sample conditional on the values of the previous two, I think.
